# why do continuations execute in an unpredictable order?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

If I chain continuations together they appear to be executing in an order I wasn't expecting.

For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    Task<JsonResult<MyResult>> message = Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + " started");
            return client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        })
        .ContinueWith<JsonResult<MyResult>>((r) =>
            {
                var stringresult = r.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult<MyResult>>(stringresult);
                Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Id + " deserialized");
                return deserialized;
            })
        .ContinueWith<JsonResult<MyResult>>(m =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Id + " completed");
                return m.Result;
            });

}
```

Now I'd expect to see the different requests interleaved, which I do, but I'm expecting to see each individual process execute in the order: started, deserialized, completed. However, sometimes the 'completed' continuation executes before the deserialization continuation, like so:

> 1 started
>   2 started
>   3 started
>   4 started
>   1 deserialized, length: 69
>   1 completed
>   5 started
>   5 deserialized, length: 831
>   **2 completed**
>   4 deserialized, length: 1022
>   3 completed
>   3 deserialized, length: 356
>   4 completed
>   **2 deserialized, length: 878**
>   5 completed

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Yes I know about the closure, the real code is much longer, and of course handles this, but I stripped out the guff that I didn't think was pertinent to the question, and then everyone goes and focuses on the missing guff!! It doesn't change the question or the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Is this your real code? I'm asking this because you're making the widespread mistake of closing over the loop variable. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx  This could lead to printing "5 started" multiple times.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Which version of C# you are you using?

Comment: I suspect some buffering/locking in Console.WriteLine(). Try adding a Stopwatch and printing StopWatch.ElapsedTicks to see if it really *is* doing what you think.

Comment: Your code does not match the result. e.g. there is no length printed in the code. Also, the id:s printed are messed up. The first one prints the loop index, the second one prints something from the deserialization and the third prints the task id. You are not comparing the same thing

Comment: Since the code you've shown doesn't include a `length` in its `WriteLine` calls, it's possible that you've obscured the actual issue when anonymizing the code.

Comment: You also seem to have not gathered the intent of async programming.  You're doing a blocking wait on all of your async calls.  There is no value added in using your continuations you're using.  This is entirely synchronous code that just appears to be asynchronous.

Comment: @Henrik if he's in C# 5 this shouldn't be the problem

Comment: To answer the comments, I stripped a whole load of code out, to try to get to the meat. The ids I'm really using are both consistent and not affected by the closure, but including all that code would have buried the core of the issue, none of which is related to the out of sequence continuations....

Comment: @MalcomTucker Well, given that there's no way for a continuation to run before the task it is continuing, it means that *something* is wrong, and it's most likely in how you log the information, not in how the code is running.  The only other option would be that your continuations start up a new async operation so it is completing the task before it's actually "done", but that's not what the code you showed does.

Comment: Servy - thanks, that last point is what I was assuming, and you're right actually right - it is completing the task before it's actually "done". Sometimes, at the point at which the completed continuation is executing, the deserialization step hasn't finished.

Comment: @MalcomTucker That's unlikely to be the case.  It would mean that you start a new thread/task inside of the continuation, which you don't do in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your largest problem is that you are doing a synchronous wait on all of your async operations (`SendAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync`).  You're just doing these synchronous waits in a background thread.  There is no value gained from your `ContinueWith` calls at all, since all of your continuations have no asynchronous components to them.  You might as well just have your entire code inside of the original `StartWith` call; putting it in a continuation gains you nothing.

Here is an example of your program, but without the synchronous waits on the async operations:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    int id = i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} started", id);
    var result = client.SendAsync(request)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} reading", id);
            return t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} read", id);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult<MyResult>>(t.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} deserialized", id);
            return deserialized;
        });
}
```

Also note that one problem in the code that you showed us is that you were not consistently using the same identifying number when logging to the console.  I have used the loop variable throughout, to keep it clear.  I also make sure to take a copy of the loop variable so that I'm not closing over the loop variable.  I also log slightly different things that should result in more interesting results.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that doesn't focus on the closed variable!! Where are the synchronous waits?

Comment: @MalcomTucker In your code?  The two calls to `Result`.  `Result` returns the result of the task, but if the task is not yet done it performs a blocking wait until the task finishes, so that it can get the result.  In both of those occasions you should be using `ContinueWith` instead so that you don't call `Result` until the task finishes, but without doing a blocking wait.

Comment: We're getting somewhere - the completed continuation is executing before the deserialization has finished. But why?

Comment: @MalcomTucker No, it's not.  I can assure you that it's not, unless your code is *nothing* like what's posted here, in which case who knows what's going on.

Comment: @MalcomTucker It means that the problem isn't that it's executing out of order, it simply means that you were improperly logging what was happening, so it *appears* out of order to you, even though it's not.  Regardless, you should restructure the code in a manor similar to what I have shown, because while your code won't run out-of-order, it has other significant flaws that need to be addressed.

Comment: sure, appreciate your time anyway, i've given you a +1 :)

Comment: when I remove the API calls and just use simple strings I'm seeing the expected behaviour

Comment: @MalcomTucker As you've clearly removed code that is relevant to what's going on we cannot intelligently comment as to what's going on, I can just tell you that a continuation won't be executed before the task that it continues is finished, so either it's running in the proper order and you are incorrectly observing the order in your logging, or your tasks are relying on asynchronous work and as such are being marked as "completed" before you want them to be done.  That isn't happening in the code that you've posted though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Henrik says, by the time the thread runs, the value of `i` will have changed. This will make determining the order that the threads are actually running in look incorrect.

Try maybe passing the `i` in to the function:

```
  Task<JsonResult<MyResult>> message = Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpRequestMessage>(state =>  {

            Console.WriteLine(state.ToString() + " started");
            return client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        }, i )
            .ContinueWith<JsonResult<MyResult>>((r) =>
            {
                var stringresult = r.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult<MyResult>>(stringresult);
                Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Id + " deserialized");
                return deserialized;
            })
            .ContinueWith<JsonResult<MyResult>>(m =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Id + " completed");
                return m.Result;
            });
```

Comment: I know about the closure, it's all handled. The question still stands regardless - why are the continuations executed out of sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing the same id:s in your printout. Try changing the last continuation into

```
        .ContinueWith<JsonResult<MyResult>>(m =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Result.Id + " completed");
            return m.Result;
        });
```

so you at least compare the same id in the continuations.

Comment: The result Id is passed into the request (code not shown) so they are exactly the same ids.